# mongodb slow query,even with proper indexes.need optimization suggestions

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, query-optimization, mongodb-3.4

we have a **MongoDB 3.4** standalone setup with **4 vCPU,8GB Vm on gcp(e2-custom)**
it has around 10 databases which are relatively smaller.
except one database.collection has data **4.3 million** of records. this could grow even bigger as 12 million in few months.

- when the below query is run it takes around 2s to complete the request. we had tried improving the specs of the server but still its the same.
- if the query is not limited it usually has around 10,000 documents.
- We've tried to use compound indexes but its not supported on mongodb 3.4.
- we cannot move to MongoDB 5.0 as requires a change of drivers of many services we use.
- our goal is to achieve at least 400ms.
- We've exported the collection to a mongo 5.0 DB with the same specs and it achieves around 370ms.it still says a slow query and mongo explain confirms that the serial index is being used.
- we've tried archiving and moving data older than 3 month to a archive-collection increases the performance but we need these data for future uses. so need all the data in same collection

seeking your help on this matter if its possible to achieve 400ms with the existing setup

it has 5 indexes as below

```
[
    {
        "v" : 2,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "name" : "_id_",
        "ns" : "mydb.incidents"
    },
    {
        "v" : 2,
        "key" : {
            "serial" : "hashed"
        },
        "name" : "serial_hashed",
        "ns" : "mydb.incidents"
    },
    {
        "v" : 2,
        "key" : {
            "itemName" : "hashed"
        },
        "name" : "itemName_hashed",
        "ns" : "mydb.incidents"
    },
    {
        "v" : 2,
        "key" : {
            "icon" : "hashed"
        },
        "name" : "icon_hashed",
        "ns" : "mydb.incidents"
    },
    {
        "v" : 2,
        "key" : {
            "dateTime" : "hashed"
        },
        "name" : "dateTime_hashed",
        "ns" : "mydb.incidents"
    }
]
```

and the query is as below

```
db.incidents.find({
 $and: [
   { serial: "b25e1466dea0601587952692f1751355" },
   { dateTime: { $gte: "2022-04-24T23:40:02.770+08:00" } },
   { $or: [{ security: "PWM" }, { security: "PWM_NOTIFICATION" }] },
   {
     $or: [
       { itemName: /alarm_entry/i },
       { itemName: /alarm_burglar/i },
       { itemName: /switch_binary/i },
       { itemName: /camera_motion/i }
     ]
   }
 ]
 })
.sort({ dateTime: -1 })
.limit(300)
```

and this is how a document looks like

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("61da873c57d830071707e0f3"),
    "className" : "com.poolp.mycons.core.api.PubEvent",
    "serial" : "b25e1466dea0601587952692f1751355",
    "itemName" : "mqtt-server-node7_alarm_entry",
    "label" : "My Label",
    "location" : "Store",
    "fromStatus" : "ON",
    "toStatus" : "OFF",
    "security" : "PWM",
    "icon" : "DOOR",
    "dateTime" : "2022-01-09T14:56:59.418+08:00"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Hash indexes do not support queries greater than (gt). Instead, use single-field indexes for the datetTime field.

```
db.incidents.createIndex( { "dateTime": -1 } )
```

If this doesn't speed up your queries enough (I had a similar problem in the past with hash indexes. It didn't work as I expected for exact match queries)
I suggest you: 1) change the index types from hashed to tree or 2) create compound indexes in case all your queries always contain the same structure.

1)

```
db.incidents.createIndex({"serial": 1})
db.incidents.createIndex({"dateTime": -1})
db.incidents.createIndex({"security": 1})
db.incidents.createIndex({"itemName": 1})
```

2. 

```
db.incidents.createIndex( { "serial": "hashed", "dateTime": -1, "security": "hashed", "itemName" : "hashed"} )
```

Also, I suggest you use "db.collection.find().explain() " to identify if your query is indeed using the indexes and is not searching exhaustively.